# Is it possible to limit Traefik to the current (docker-compose) Stack?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rancher, traefik

### Objective

I have a server running Rancher (Docker). In that server, I have several un-related stacks.

I want to make Traefik the main interaction point of that stack. And make it load balance / proxy the requests to different containers based on the path.

I want to make it send the traffic for `/api` to the backend `server` service. And send the traffic for `/` to the `frontend`service.

### Current state

Here's a slimmed down version of my `docker-compose.yml` showing only the relevant services:

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    image: server
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/api"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=80"
  frontend:
    image: frontend
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=80"
  proxy:
    image: traefik:v1.4
    command: --web --accessLog --rancher --rancher.exposedbydefault=false --rancher.metadata=true
    volumes:
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
```

Then using a Rancher load balancer that listens to the public ports, I redirect requests to `app1.example.com` to my `proxy` service. Then it takes the requests and re-directs traffic to each of the two containers based on the path.

I also redirect traffic to `traefik.app1.example.com` to the same `proxy` service, to the port `8080` to access the web UI.

If I have only one stack, it works.

### The problem

If I add another stack (or if I duplicate that stack) and have more services with Traefik labels, the `proxy` from `app1` will read the labels from the services in `app2` and any other stack that declares Traefik labels.

Then, in the web UI for the `proxy` in `app1`, I can see all the backends from all the different stacks. But the frontend rules get overwritten.

### Question

Up to now, I've seen examples mostly of how to use Traefik as a unique global load balancer / proxy. I just realized that I assumed that I could also create isolated Traefik instances per stack, or a hierarchy of Traefik load balancers.

It seems to me like I'm  missing some configuration or misunderstanding something.

But still, I have to ask, is it possible to have different isolated Traefik instances per stack and make them only listen and use the services in their own stack?

Is it possible with Rancher? Is it possible with any other Docker stack orchestrator (e.g. Swarm)?

If that's possible, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

I think I found how to solve it.

It seems I can't make Traefik only use services in his own stack directly. But it seems I can use [Traefik constraints](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/commons/#constraints) and tags to achieve almost the same.

Here's my updated `docker-compose.yml` using constraints and tags:

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    image: server
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/api"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.tags=app1.example.com"
  frontend:
    image: frontend
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.tags=app1.example.com"
  proxy:
    image: traefik:v1.4
    command: --web --accessLog --constraints=tag==app1.example.com --rancher --rancher.exposedbydefault=false --rancher.metadata=true
    volumes:
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
```

It will only match services that have the Traefik tag `app1.example.com`. Those tags can be any string, but as I'm wanting to filter by a specific domain, I just used the domain I wanted to filter as the tag to use.

Also, notice that the tag is set in the services with a label `traefik.tag`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer. I feel the docs would had taken a lot of time to help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in Traefik v2 solution for this, you can use `--providers.docker.constraints` option to achieve the same result.
So, the basic example could be:

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3
    command:
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.constraints=Label(`custom.label`,`custom-value`)"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  custom_service:
    image: ...
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "custom.label=custom-value"
```

[Docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/docker/#constraints)